# How to use SSo with firebase authentication for web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement sso with firebase authentication and i am trying to use without using third party like okta and wanted to know is it any workaround with this.basically the use case like this

A client wanted to build a custom SSO solution and had already chosen Firebase, based on Google’s promise to rollout SSO support in the future. The client did not want migration to any other SSO provider like Auth0 or Identity Server, or to deal with user-password migration and potential related issues. They preferred instead to use a temporary, custom solution that would store user’s passwords in Firebase Authentication.

The client had several customer portals based on WordPress Customer Relationship Management (CRM) and an existing list of users in Firebase Authentication. Each time users visited a new portal, credentials were required, and again when users followed a link from one portal to another. It was not always obvious for users that the same credentials should be used for different portals.

By default, Firebase keeps authentication context for one domain but doesn’t provide seamless SSO integration between different domains. To provide this functionality, SoftServe determined that a new Firebase service should be implemented.